# quickest way to find broken DIVs

Tags: html

I have a site that is calling a great deal of HTML from a third party source. Trouble is, I think they are returning malformed code to me.

I need a quick way to find additional DIV closures, is this possible?

Comment: have you tried putting the HTML code you want to check through an HTML IDE? usually structural problems are highlighted immediately in the code editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a page calling just the provided code then validate it - [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Blogger doesn't let you save a page if it's broken.

Answer (score 4):

Just install [View shource chart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-source-chart/?src=api) add on for firefox and u can find the source generated in a formatted manner which is easy to find the unwanted tags..

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

http://www.tormus.com/en/tools/div_checker

Will find non matching divs for you. Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try [w3 org validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

While an IDE is not specifically mentioned, I would highly recommend putting the code into an IDE.

In Dreamweaver CS6 you can Validate directly to WC3 from within Dreamweaver. When an error is found you can go directly to that portion of the code and leverage the tools of the IDE.